# Draw 3D Implied Volatility Graph

Tags: r, 3d, data-visualization, quantmod, volatility

I am trying to draw a [3d](/questions/tagged/3d) Implied [volatility](/questions/tagged/volatility) Graph For BAC company. I did the codes to draw `implied volatility` vs `Strike Prices` (below). The plot code below will draw the graph for Implied Volatility vs Strike prices on just ONE date (Mar.27.2020)

May I know how do I edit my codes to draw a 3D graph which draws the Implied Volatility VS Strike Prices and Time To maturity please?

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("jsonlite")
install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("fOptions")
library(quantmod)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
library(fOptions)

# Getting option chain data of Bank of America (all expiries)
CHAIN <- getOptionChain("BAC", NULL)
# Setting maturity of options as T (in years)
maturity <- as.Date(names(CHAIN), format="%b.%d.%Y")
today <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), format="%Y-%m-%d")
T <- as.numeric((maturity - today)/365)
# Interest Rate = 2%pa
r = 0.02;ImpVol<-1:1
# Getting latest price of Bank of America shares
getSymbols("BAC",from=today,to=today,src="yahoo")
S=as.numeric(Ad(`BAC`))
# Plot implied volatility over strike price given market prices of options (blue line)
for (i in 1:length(CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Strike)){ImpVol[i]<- GBSVolatility(CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Last[i], "c", S, CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Strike[i], T[1], r, 0)}

  #GBSVolatility(CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Last[i], "c", S, CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Strike[i],0.00274, r, 0)}
length(CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Strike)
length(ImpVol)
plot(CHAIN$Mar.27.2020$calls$Strike[!is.na(ImpVol)], ImpVol[!is.na(ImpVol)], xlab = "Strike price", ylab = "Implied volatility", lwd =3, type = "l", col
     = "blue")
```